# how http permanent and temporary redirects work in form submission scenario

Tags: http, http-headers

lets say i have a form in www.example.com/registration.php and the form submits to  www.example.com/process.php and redirects to www.example.com/welcome.php. so when i click submit a post response is generated and sent to process.php. from there a redirect code is sent lets say 301 (permanentit) as a response with location www.example.com/welcome.php.
My questions
1)in wikipedia it says

> If the 301(or same case  in 302,for 303,307) status code is received in
>   response to a request of any type other than GET or HEAD, the client
>   must ask the user before redirecting

so if i submit i should be asked for confirmation but this never happens it directly goes to welcome.php page

2)whats the difference between 301-permanent and 302(also 303, 307) -temporary redirect when used in form submission scenario explained above

3)i cant really get it from the following

> > The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
> >     permanent redirection, meaning current links or records using the URL
> >     that the 301 Moved Permanently response is received for should be
> >     updated to the new URL provided in the Location field of the response.
> >     This status code should be used with the location header. RFC 2616
> >     states that:  If a client has link-editing capabilities, it should
> >     update all references to the Request URI.

what is it with  updating all links to new uri is to do with browsers(user agents). whether it is meant only for search engine indexing

and finally

search engine doesn't index temporary redirects and permanent redirect replaces the current request url to new url from redirect response. whether search engine also takes into account 
the above submission and if i give a 301 redirect response in process.php to redirect to
welcome.php then registration.php will be replaced by welcome.php in search engine index database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally ill-advised to use 301 or 302 responses to redirect any requests that aren't GET or HEAD requests, and many user agents do not support this.

I suspect your terminology is a bit confused. As I understand it /process.php handles a request from /registration.php and issues a response with a 301 status code asking the user agent to go to /welcome.php. The scenario you are quoting from RFC 2616 is that the server recieves a POST request to /process.php and redirects the POST request itself to /process_v2.php, which then processes the request. The initial POST isn't actually redirected in your example, the result of the POST contains a redirect to welcome.php, which will then be retrieved using a GET request.

I'm not sure I understand your search engine question, as far as I know search engines don't submit forms, so I don't believe that welcome.php will ever be indexed.

Comment: thanks for your answer.you said 301 and 302 should not be used to redirect any requests that aren't GET. so while submitting forms its normally a post request so after successfully processing the post values and storing it in database u generally have to redirect to show some success message.what should be done in this case. and i have also learned in ruby on rails that if you submit a form and if it is successful always use redirect_to method to redirect to another page or same page itself . the redirect to method mentioned here always redirects with 307 temporary redirect by default.

Comment: sorry,i believe i understood the concept in wrong way.i think i misunderstood the statement "If the 301(or same case in 302,for 303,307) status code is received in response to a request of any type other than GET or HEAD" i thaught what the request meant here is the original form submission request not the redirect requset by the server.i think to redirect request that are other than GET we can use 307.correct me if i am wrong.thanks